# How do I disable tap-to-click on the touchpad in Ubuntu Gnome 17.04?

Tags: touchpad, ubuntu-gnome

There are no options to disable 'tap-to-click' in Mouse and Touch-pad settings, but there have always been in previous Ubuntu releases.[image]

Comment: Can this be made active now? 17.04 stable is out.

Comment: Nominated for re-opening.

Comment: Try `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click false`. Does this work?

Comment: Already tried gsettings (before posting here). Has no effect.

Comment: @user308393 That exact schema? Did you get any errors or does it go through properly?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just registered to spread the solution to this annyoing problem.

Make sure you have package xserver-xorg-input-libinput installed. Then you need to remove package xserver-xorg-input-synaptics and restart. After the restart you have all the options back in the GUI.

Everything is handled by xserver-xorg-input-libinput now. xserver-xorg-input-synaptics is interfering this.

Comment: In my case, xserver-xorg-input-libinput was already installed. All I had to do was remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics and reboot. Thanks!

Comment: thanks a lot, this helped. how this managed to pass beta tests is beyond me...

Comment: Exactly my problem on an Asus UX501V!

Comment: This also works on Ubuntu 17.10. I just had to remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics and restart, and all the settings were there!

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to disable tap-to-click for the synaptics driver by changing its configuration in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` to set `Option "MaxTapTime" "0"`. Here is some documetation on [synaptics driver configuration options](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Disable_touchpad_while_typing).

Switching from `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` to `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` did give me the option in the settings UI to disable tap-to-click, which worked; however, the driver switch also resulted in the loss of the ability to right-click with a two-finger click.

This was for a Dell XPS 13.